# A finite subset of an ordered set contains an $\inf$ and $\sup$

Tags: order-theory

Let S be an ordered set. Let A ⊂ S be a nonempty finite subset. Then A is bounded.
Furthermore, inf A exists and is in A and sup A exists and is in A. Hint: Use induction.

How do I use induction to prove that the infinum and supremum exist?

Comment: Even though this is phrased in more generality, the answer here applies (as would any answer to that question): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/259893/ That answer shows specifically how to use induction to show that $\sup A$ exists and is in $A$, and it can be adapted to prove the same about the $\inf$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/548806/