# Minimization of a linear functional over a set by support function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

My question comes from the famous book: `convex analysis, Rockafellar Ch. 13`

[image]

> My question is the minimization over $C$ should be $-\delta^*(x^* \mid C)$.  Why is the answer $-\delta^*(-x^* \mid C)$?
>
> My point is that if we I get $\delta^*(x^* \mid C)$, the maximum value of $x^*$ over $C$, the minimum is nothing but the minus sign of it.

Note: A related question just for reference:

["Support function of a set" and supremum question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686641/support-function-of-a-set-and-supremum-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\inf_{x \in S} \, f(x) = - \sup_{x \in S} -f(x)$.

The smallest possible value of $f$ is the same as the largest possible value of $-f$, except the signs are flipped.

So the formula $-\delta^*(-x^* | C)$ is correct.